# can't stop program randomizing. Pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Ye i know this is quite noob question but problem is this.
i'm making a game and i wanna randomize stars to a huge space area

But results that i get are:

1. The space keeps recaculating places of stars so everything moves.
2. It Shows only 1 star on the upper left corner of window.

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

gstars = 500
gstarmax = 0
red = (255,0,0)
yellow = (240,250,60)
timer = 0
size = [1600, 1000]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 1000), HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF | RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.set_caption('planet system test')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

area = pygame.image.load("screenMonitor.png")


done = False
while done == False:
    pygame.event.pump()
    mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    timer += 1
    if timer > 99:
        timer = 0
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (20, 20, 1350, 480), 2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(2,2,2,2),2)
    go = True
    if go == True:
        for i in range(gstars):
            s1 = random.randrange(1,1600)
            s2 = random.randrange(1,1000)
            colorSelect = random.randrange(0,5)


            if colorSelect == 1:
                yellow = (240,250,60)

            if colorSelect == 2:
                yellow = (249,173,60)

            if colorSelect == 3:
                yellow = (226,43,68)

            if colorSelect == 4:
                yellow = (52,173,84)

            go = False
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(2+s1,2+s2,2,2),2)





    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is in the main/event loop.

You put the code for position your stars inside the main loop. Since it is randomize at every iteration, it will move.

I remove the `go = False` that probably cause the error to display only one star.

In the following code, I create a list of star that have the position in indices 0 and 1, and the tuple of the color in 2.
The tuple of color is randomly choose using the `random.choice(Sequence)` function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random

gstars = 500
gstarmax = 0
red = (255,0,0)
yellow = (240,250,60)
timer = 0
size = [1600, 1000]

    pygame.init()    
    pygame.display.set_caption('planet system test')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size[0], size[1]))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    area = pygame.image.load("screenMonitor.png")

    color = ((240,250,60),(249,173,60),(226,43,68),(52,173,84))
    stars = []
    for i in range(gstars):
        s1 = random.randrange(1,1600)
        s2 = random.randrange(1,1000)
        starcolor = random.choice(color)
        stars.append([s1, s2, starcolor])

    done = False
    while done == False:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #Quit the game if X 
                done = False

        screen.fill(0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (20, 20, 1350, 480), 2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(2,2,2,2),2)
        for star in stars:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,star[2],(2+star[0],2+star[1],2,2),2)


        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(30)
```

**EDIT** : Correct the code following the advice of Ted Klein Bergman.

Comment: Code seems to work it generates the star correctly but the program gets stuck. It Does not give any crash messages it just stops responding. Tried to figure it out but saw nothing was wrong in there.

Comment: Sorry, a small mistake in my code : `pygame.event.pump()`. Forget the ().
I prefer to use the following code to quit the main loop of pygame         
`for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type is pygame.QUIT: #Quit the game if X
                done = False`

Comment: Ye i added 'pygame.quit()' to it but it still does it. And does this run the star generation just once? EDIT: oh sorry my bad it runs the stars know and wont crash seems to work know

Comment: Just know started thinking would it be smarter to make class or def out of this?

Comment: @simonLECLERC You'd probably check equality instead of identity in the event loop. The `event.type` is an integer, and checking identity works for small enough integers because Python generates an array of integer objects between -5 to 256 at the start of the program. Integers outside this range won't have the same identity and thus will evaluate to False. Checking for equality (`if event.type == pygame.QUIT`) is more secure and not based on a abstract implementation, which makes it the better choice. Also, rename `Color` to `color` instead. Names with capital first letter indicates classes

Comment: @TedKleinBergman, thanks for the advice. cmdtvt, using class and function is more pythonic. For example a class with ScreenMonitor and inside function(s) to create/randomize the display on pygame.